# How to simulate data from a logit model

Tags: r, regression, simulate, ecdf

I have a logistic regression, and I would like to generate simulated data from the logit curve. My code is below:

```
    #Begin Code        
    require(gld)

    runs<-100
    num.trees<-500
    p<-0.5

    trial.1<-rgl(num.trees,1859.75592, 0.02179, -0.09578, 0.24264, param = "fkml", lambda5 =    NULL)
    trial.1 <- floor(trial.1/10)*10+1

    minDecade <- min(trial.1)
    maxDecade <- max(trial.1)
    allDecades <- seq(minDecade-100, 2001, by=10) 

    x<-1:length(allDecades)
    y<-sample(trial.1, p*num.trees)


binTrees <- rep(0,length(allDecades))

for (i in 1:length(allDecades)) {

        binTrees[i] <- length(which(y==allDecades[i]))
    }
        binTrees


    binTrees<-cumsum(binTrees)/sum(binTrees)

    fit<-glm(binTrees~x,family=binomial(link='logit'))

    plot(binTrees)
    lines(fitted.values(fit))

    #End Code
```

Basically, from this last bit, how can generate simulated data from my logistic regression? 
Someone I spoke with recommended using a CDF function to do this, but I wouldn't know where to begin. My goal is to recreate a full data set based on my fitted curve.

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: From this question, it sounds like you might best benefit from consulting with a statistician. A good place to start in lieu of that, in my opinion, would be the arm package and the references therein.

Answer (score 0):

You would generally be drawing from a binomial distribution if you were doing a simulation experiment using logistic regression:

```
> set.seed(123)
> df1 <- data.frame(event=rbinom(n=20, size=1, prob=.4) )
> glm(event ~ . , df1, family="binomial")

Call:  glm(formula = event ~ ., family = "binomial", data = df1)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)  
    -0.4055  

Degrees of Freedom: 19 Total (i.e. Null);  19 Residual
Null Deviance:      26.92 
Residual Deviance: 26.92    AIC: 28.92 
> exp(-0.4055)/(1+exp(-0.4055))
[1] 0.3999916
> sum(df1$event)/length(df1$event)
[1] 0.4  # that degree of agreement with the simulated parameter is accidental.
```

The connection between your `rgl` functional result (based on an unnamed package) and the rest of the code seems obscure, so it would be better if you described in natural natural language what you are hoping to simulate.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to fit a logistic curve to a subsampled set of data. Then, based on that curve, I want to recreate a data set that is the same size as the original (the data that was subsampled). I hope to see the consequences that different levels of sampling have on parameter estimation.

Comment: Also, the rgl function, and gld package are just used to create a distribution of dates, which are then binned into decades... it doesn't have much to do with my main object here.  I use them to create a data set from which to subsample.

Comment: @jtgarcia, this sounds a bit like bootstrapping, rather than simulating from a distribution based on a fitted model. Would bootstrapping do what you are trying to accomplish?